# puppet bind dns camptocamp simple example not working

Tags: dns, puppet, bind

Trying puppet dns module from camptocamp but its not working.

My class and the Simple Example code from forge puppet camptocamp bind README to create a zone and a record:

```
class profile::dnsbind::server {

bind::zone {'example.com':
  ensure       => 'present',
  zone_contact => 'contact.example.com',
  zone_ns      => ['ns0.example.com'],
  zone_serial  => '2012112901',
  zone_ttl     => '604800',
  zone_origin  => 'example.com',
}

bind::a { 'example.com':
  ensure    => 'present',
  zone      => 'example.com',
  ptr       => false,
  hash_data => {
    'host1' => { owner => '192.168.0.1', },
    'host2' => { owner => '192.168.0.2', },
  },
}
}
```

Error message:

```
Error: Failed to apply catalog: Could not find dependency Package[bind9] for Concat::Fragment[default.zone.example.com] at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/bind/manifests/zone.pp:85
```

Error message follow up zone.pp row 85:

```
concat::fragment {"${_view}.zone.${name}":
    target  => "${bind::params::views_directory}/${_view}.zones",
    content => "include \"${bind::params::zones_directory}/${name}.conf\";\n",
    notify  => Exec['reload bind9'],
    require => Package['bind9'],
  }
```

Modules:

```
/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules
├── camptocamp-bind (v1.4.3)
├── drzewiec-chrony (v1.0.2)
├── puppetlabs-concat (v1.2.5)
└── puppetlabs-stdlib (v4.25.1)
```

Dependencies:

```
puppetlabs/stdlib (>=3.2.0 <5.0.0)
puppetlabs/concat (>= 1.0.0 <2.0.0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs for this module are mediocre at best, but after looking through the code to find what class actually declares `Package[bind9]`, I worked my way backward and eventually discovered this easy-to-overlook item in [the "classes" section of the docs](https://forge.puppet.com/camptocamp/bind/readme#classes):

> **bind**
>
> This class must be declared before using the definitions in this
>   module.

You are using the defined types, but you have not declared the `bind` class.  Correct that by putting this in your profile class:

```
include 'bind'
```

If you need to customize its parameters (you'll need to look at the source to find out what they are) then put the appropriate parameter values in your external data.

---

I note, by the way, that this particular module has received abysmal community reviews, at least in part because of poor docs.  There are several other bind modules on the forge with better reviews, and, IMO much better docs.  That's not to say that `camptocamp-bind` won't work just fine for you, but it's not the one *I* would have tried first.